# Period before Doctype

Tags: html, utf-8, doctype

A period before my doctype (on localhost) is pushing all my head meta information from `<head>` into `<body>`.

Having done some research it was suggested that it was to do with using UTF-8 with BOM instead of without, however, I have checked and double-checked (even using the W3C validator) and it's using without BOM.

Are there any other reasons this would be happening?

Comment: Are you using any analytics of any kind? I have seen some weird things inserted into pages when some analytics scripts are used. Try testing with a really minimal page. Do you get the same results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the issue was in the end, but I created a new header.php, copy and pasted the content into it and everything then worked.

Comment: F*cking brilliant! I've spent all night trying to fix this stupid issue! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The period (or an extraneous BOM) will make the HTML parser think that the body element has started. So it goes into "parse the body" mode and everything that follows is put into the body section.

---

The byte sequence which is a BOM when it is the first bytes of a Unicode file is a "zero width no break space" character at any other place in the file. It's therefore a printable character like a period or "&nbsp;" or "x" and if the parser sees it before body has started will simply assume that a `<html>` `<head>` and `<body>` tags not seen were simply omitted by the author of the page, since they are all optional in HTML.

The reason why a BOM is often suspected is that it is invisible and usually added by a tool rather than manually by the author, so the author is unaware that it is there. This is not the case for a period character.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was an extra character accidentally at the top of /var/www/wordpress/wp-config.php